# java aes javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded

Tags: java, encryption, nullpointerexception, aes

```
public class AES {

    public String getEncrypt(String pass){
        String password = encrypt(pass);
        return password;
    }

    public String getDecrypt(String pass){
        String key = "AesSEcREtkeyABCD";
        byte[] passwordByte = decrypt(key,pass);
        String password = new String(passwordByte);
        return password;
    }

    private byte[] decrypt(String key, String encrypted) {
        try {
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes(), "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, new SecretKeySpec(skeySpec.getEncoded(), "AES"));
            //getting error here
            byte[] original = cipher.doFinal(encrypted.getBytes());
            return original;
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    } 

    private String encrypt(String value) {
        try {
            byte[] raw = new byte[]{'A', 'e', 's', 'S', 'E', 'c', 'R', 'E', 't', 'k', 'e', 'y','A','B','C','D'};
            SecretKeySpec skeySpec = new SecretKeySpec(raw, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, skeySpec);
            byte[] encrypted = cipher.doFinal(value.getBytes());
            System.out.println("encrypted string:" + (new String(encrypted)));
            return new String(encrypted);
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();       
        } catch (BadPaddingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

**
I am having a null pointer whenever I decrypt. sometimes it gives me the correct decrypted password but sometimes it gives me a null pointer. can't guess what the problem is here **

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are mixing Strings and byte arrays.  That is not always a good thing to do.  At the very least specify what charset you are using for the byte to char conversion.  Even then it is not 100% safe.  Better to treat strings as strings and byte arrays as byte arrays.

If that does not solve it then there are many things that can cause a "Bad Padding" error.  Basically anything that causes the end of the last block not to match the expected padding will throw the error.  Possible causes include: incorrect padding setting, incorrect key, corrupted cyphertext and others.

To try and diagnose the problem, set the decryption side to `NoPadding`.  This will accept anything, and allow you to examine the output:

- complete garbage: you probably have an error in the key or different mode settings.
- first block garbage: you may have a key error or an IV error.
- last block garbage: likely a corrupt end to the cyphertext file.
- a correct decryption with some strange bytes at the end: the strange bytes are the padding.

If it really is just the padding, then set the decryption function to expect that sort of padding.  Otherwise check that the key/IV/cyphertext is **byte-for-byte** the same for both encryption and decryption.

It is *vital* that you set a padding mode after diagnosis.  `NoPadding` is insecure.

Comment: `"NoPadding"` is only insecure for RSA. `"NoPadding"` is slightly *more* secure than padding for symmetric ciphers as padding oracles are not possible anymore. Of course, a mode like CBC is a lot less functional without padding.

Comment: `NoPadding` is also insecure against some forms of transmission corruption.  Any transmission error in, or propagating to, the last block will trigger a `BadPaddingException` if some form of padding is expected.  `NoPadding` will ignore all such exceptions.  You pays your money and you takes your choice.

Comment: We'll stay in disagreement here I guess. But I already voted up and the rest of the answer did appear to satisfy Allen, so that's OK :)