# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded - when decryptText

Tags: java, encryption

When Dycrypt plain text then throw BadPaddingException
javax.crypto.BadPaddingException: Given final block not properly padded
com.sun.crypto.provider.CipherCore.doFinal(CipherCore.java:811)

```
private static final String ENCRYPTION_KEY = "harshitorld!@#$%"; 
private static byte[] randomBytesToDecrypt;
private static final String ALGORITHM = "Rijndael";
private static final String UNICODE_FORMAT = "UTF8";
private static String encrypt(String value) {
    try {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        c.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] encValue = c.doFinal(value.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT));
        String encryptedValue = new BASE64Encoder().encode(encValue);
        return encryptedValue;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

public static String decrypt(String encryptedValue) {
    try {
        Key key = generateKey();
        Cipher c = Cipher.getInstance(ALGORITHM);
        c.init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key);
        byte[] decordedValue = new BASE64Decoder().decodeBuffer(encryptedValue);
        byte[] decValue = c.doFinal(decordedValue);//////////LINE 50
        String decryptedValue = new String(decValue,UNICODE_FORMAT);
        return decryptedValue;
    } catch (Exception ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}

private static Key generateKey() throws Exception {
    byte[] keyAsBytes;
    keyAsBytes = ENCRYPTION_KEY.getBytes(UNICODE_FORMAT);
    Key key = new SecretKeySpec(keyAsBytes, ALGORITHM);
    return key;
}

public static String encryptText(String normalText) {
    return encrypt(normalText);
}

public static String decryptText(String encryptedText) {
    return decrypt(encryptedText);
}
```

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26529950/java-aes-javax-crypto-badpaddingexception-given-final-block-not-properly-padded/26532289#26532289 for some suggestions.

Comment: Do you actually try to "Decrypt plain text" (= text that is not encrypted) ? If you do, you will get the Padding exception as random data mostly don't decrypt to something that have a proper padding. If not, please provide a verifiable example of your problem.